Optional property with question mark defaults to nil but Optional property with generic notation does not
This compiles, because nil is supplied as a default value:
class MyCoolClass {
    var myProperty: Int? // ok
}

This does not compile:
class MyCoolClass {
    var myProperty: Optional<Int> // error
}

Why? I thought Int? was pure and simple syntactic sugar for Optional<Int>, so why does the choice of notation matter? Why doesn't the second one compile when the first one does?

By inspecting the compiler source code, writing Optional<Int> was valid until Swift 5, so this change is probably for stylistic reasons, e.g. encourage people to use the sugar syntax.

See isDefaultInitializable in Decl.cpp.

@Sweeper You don't think there's any chance the change might have been inadvertent?

@matt Yeah, now that you mention it. The support for the desugared syntax is added in this commit, which is a commit for Swift 5. This means that it wasn't actually valid before Swift 5, but isn't valid in Swift 5 either, because of the !ctx.isSwiftVersionAtLeast(5) check. To get it to work you need a Swift 5+ compiler, but pass a -swift-version option, which is very weird.

Perhaps the ! was mistyped. In any case, I think you should submit an issue.

You seem to understand it a lot better than I do, maybe you should submit the issue. :) — Either way, it would be great if you can come up with an answer that expresses what you think is going on here. No rush.

Okay, I submitted this issue.

Beautifully written; I've subscribed to notifications for the issue.

Thx for catching that... I'm still learning the optionals and generics, and I will say as someone that had so-so programing experience in other languages, the biggest downside to optionals is that the ? ! punctuation has too many uses, and Swift.org doesn't have a punctuation disambiguation page, the way wikipedia would... I think I'd like to use this generic's format in my code, just bc it's a lot clearer (to me at least)
